# C++：cannot seek vector iterator before begin

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I was doing a uva problem [uva 10935 throwing cards away](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1876), and my code is as follows. when i ran it, it said An unhandled exception was raised: read access conflict, and it also shows "cannot seek vector iterator before begin", i don't know where is the problem in my code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
vector<int> out;


int main() {
    freopen("data.txt", "r", stdin);
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n) {
        vector<int> cards;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)cards.push_back(i);
        vector<int>::iterator it = cards.begin();
        vector<int>::iterator end = cards.end();
        while (it != (end-1)) {
            out.push_back(*it);
            it++;
            cards.push_back(*it);
            it++;
            end++;
        }
        cout << "Discarded cards: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < out.size(); j++) {
            if(j!=(out.size()-1))cout << out[j] << ", ";
            else cout << out[j] << endl;

        }
        cout << "Remaining card: " << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a problem with end++, and others iterators.

If the vector cards grows, its memory location may be changed, and end++ will be pointing to an invalide position. Similar happens with it++.

I propose you to use lists instead:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n;

int main() {
    //freopen("a.in", "r", stdin);

    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n) {

        list<int> out;

        list<int> cards;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
          cards.push_back(i);
        list<int>::iterator it = cards.begin();

        list<int>::iterator end = cards.end();
        end--;
        while (it != (end)) {
            out.push_back(*it);
            it++;
            cards.push_back(*it);
            it++;
            end++;
        }
        cout << "Discarded cards: ";
        list<int>::iterator it2 = out.begin();
        for (int j = 0; j < out.size(); j++, it2++) {
            if(j !=(out.size()-1))
               cout << *it2 << ", ";
            else
              cout << *it2 << endl;
        }
        cout << "Remaining card: " << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: I haven't read the UVA problem.

Comment: The term you're looking for is iterator invalidation. See [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). The real fix would be to stop caching `end` and instead use `cards.end()` while the vector's size is being modified. And `std::list` has far worse performance than `std::vector` because it is not a cache-friendly data structure

Comment: @alterigel Ok, I partially agree. `cards.end()` is what I proposed first. Then I runned the program and still crashing, and then I see that the problem persists with it++. So i changed my answer: For non changing a lot of the original code, I proposed lists. The code has the same asyntotical time complexity, and is what (usually) matters for get Accepted in online judges

Comment: I think you missed that the iterator `it` is also possibly invalidated by `push_back`

Comment: @alterigel well, what I've said in my previous comment is I missed that, then I changed my answer to use lists. The problem doesn't persists with lists.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here remains in the while() loop, where you are ***pushing new element in the vector*** while ***holding it's old "end" address as terminal reference***.

When a vector pushes a new element, it may need to reallocate it's whole array to a new location. In that case, the "***end***" *reference that you are holding will become obsolete as you are increasing it linearly, **but the whole vector after that push may have shifted somewhere else.***

I added some debug lines in your code, so you can see how this happens. **Just run the code with an input value of 4**. And you will see the "end" value probably will not relate with the vector's reallocated address anymore (if reallocation happens, it basically depends on the system to decide).

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
vector<int> out;

void printVectorElementAddresses(vector<int> &v){
    cout<<"==== Vector Element Addresses ====\n";
    for(auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout<<&(*itr);
        if(itr == v.end()-1){
            cout<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<" ";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void printIteratorAddressWithTag(char* tag, vector<int> :: iterator & it, bool printNewLine){
    cout<<tag<<&*it<<"; ";
    if(printNewLine){
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
//    freopen("data.txt", "r", stdin);
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n) {
        vector<int> cards;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)cards.push_back(i);
        vector<int>::iterator it = cards.begin();
        vector<int>::iterator end = cards.end();

        //print vector addresses after initial pushes are done
        printVectorElementAddresses(cards);

        while (it != (end-1)) {
            printIteratorAddressWithTag("it initial = ", it, false);
            out.push_back(*it);
            it++;

            printIteratorAddressWithTag("it after first increment = ", it, false);
            cards.push_back(*it);
            it++;

            printIteratorAddressWithTag("it after second increment = ", it, true);

            printIteratorAddressWithTag("end initially in loop = ", end, false);
            end++;

            printIteratorAddressWithTag("end after increment = ", end, true);

            cout<<"Vector Addresses after a new push"<<endl;
            printVectorElementAddresses(cards);
        }
        cout << "Discarded cards: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < out.size(); j++) {
            if(j!=(out.size()-1))cout << out[j] << ", ";
            else cout << out[j] << endl;

        }
        cout << "Remaining card: " << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just change the logic in your while loop to keep track of the old "end" reference after the push happens. And if the other logic are fine, it should work.